# Sequelize write model separate file with intellisense

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

This is my code for the model

```
const {DataTypes} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define(
        "category",
        {
            name:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            color:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                defaultValue: 'red'
            }
        },       

    );
  
    return Category;
 };
```

and in the index.js (main Sequelize  config)

```
const db = {}

db.Sequelize = Sequelize
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.notes  = require('./note')(sequelize)
db.categories  = require('./category')(sequelize)
```

My problem is that the sequelize object in the model is as a parameter and I have no intellisense for the options of the object.

How can I set the model in separate file and get the intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possible ways forward I can see:

1. Export `sequelize` instance from the index.js instead of using as a function parameter
2. Utilize Sequelize's [class Model definition](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#extending-model)
3. Use Typescript